Next.js suppressHydrationWarning doesn't work as expected after deployment on Vercel
I'm importing the HouseTableUpdatedDate component into a server component (app/page.tsx).
The Vercel Build Server's location differs from mine, so I converted the component into a client-side component using use client and utilized suppressHydrationWarning to display the date in my timezone and avoid hydration error.
However, it displays Vercel's timezone on production. The updatedAt is a millisecond number.
Where did I go wrong?
'use client';

import { updatedDateStyle } from './HouseTableUpdatedDate.css';

interface Props {
  updatedAt: number;
}

const HouseTableUpdatedDate = (props: Props) => {
  const { updatedAt } = props;

  const updatedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ko', {
    dateStyle: 'full',
    timeStyle: 'medium',
  }).format(updatedAt);

  return (
    <p className={updatedDateStyle} suppressHydrationWarning>
      {updatedDate}
    </p>
  );
};

export default HouseTableUpdatedDate;

